# How2 remove a tree animation hidden in a Rustle Phase of vertex colors?

Tags: animation

After weeks of research elsewhere, I still need help with tricky tree animation … a tree animation hidden in a Rustle Phase of vertex colors.

the game : the sims 4
the modding tool : sims4studio
the purpose : modify / cloning debug trees and remove/modify rustle animation
my level : super newb
my blender : 2.78c
context : finish my k-707 mod ( which replaces all the trees of the game )

If most of the game’s trees have a reasonable rustle animation with no problem, few ( 4 / 5 trees ) are just acting crazy.

A sims 4 tree in blender has no rig …

The ONLY one information I got is this :

> Swaying tree animation actually uses the model’s vertex color data to
> do leaf rustle. It does not use skinning in the sense of setting up
> bones and weights the way typical objects do.
>
> So the short answer is that when cloning a tree, you cannot lose the
> any of the vert color data. I suspect whatever tool(s) you are using
> to do the cloning is losing this data, since this setup is somewhat
> unique to trees.
>
> Technical details: The vertex color layout for trees is as follows.
> Green and Blue are ignored for channels 1…4: Color 0 RGB Surface color
> tint Color 1 R Rustle direction X Color 2 R Rustle direction Y Color 3
> R Rustle direction Z Color 4 R Rustle phase (game generates two wind
> scales that change over time, this term interpolates between the two)
>
> The pipeline keeps the rustle information in a vertex color format for
> what the game engine will load, which means it’s in the range 0 and 1.
> The shader remaps this into a 0.5 to -0.5 range before scaling it and
> applying the offset to the leaves. Note that these directions are
> clamped but not normalized (they’re allowed to be different lengths).
> The WindMagnitude material parameter acts as a scaling factor.

Thanks in advance

Comment: An illustration (gif?) of the final effect would  help here, I think...